# putIfAbsent for immutable maps?

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, concurrency, immutability

I often find myself writing code like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

var foos = Map.empty[Int, Foo]

def fooOf(n: Int): Foo = {
  foos.get(n) match {
    case Some(foo) => foo
    case None =>
      val foo = new Foo(n)
      foos = foos.updated(n, foo)
      foo
  }
}
```

With a concurrent map, the code looks much nicer:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent._

var foos = TrieMap.empty[Int, Foo]

def fooOf(n: Int): Foo = {
  val foo = new Foo(n)
  foos.putIfAbsent(n, foo) getOrElse foo
}
```

But I really want a non-concurrent, immutable map. Is there something like `putIfAbsent` for it?

(By the way, in the concurrent example, is it possible to create the `Foo` only if it is indeed absent?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with a mutable variable (and seems like you are as you used `var foos` in both examples and only specified an immutable collection) this should match your needs:

```
var foos = Map.empty[Int, Foo]

def fooOf(n: Int): Foo = {
  foos.getOrElse(n, {
    foos = foos.updated(n, new Foo(n))
    foos(n)
  })
}
```

Comment: You can do foos.getOrElse(n, { /* not found, do something else */ }) with just one call.

Comment: Thanks @DCKing - just edited answer to use the map's getOrElse

Comment: This is not good idea, it has side effect and no works with concurrency.